# Difference between : and =

Tags: swift, variables, xcode7, var

I have been programming in Swift for quite a while. But still I haven't got down the whole of the basics and haven't understood the difference between '=' and ':'. We use these to declare variables. But what is the difference between equal to and a colon while programming in Swift? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

With `:` you are declaring a type and with `=` you are assigning a value.

Check out the section ["Type Annotations"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) in the Apple Swift guide.

---

In response to the comment:

> when we use = also while declaring the type. For example- var anyVariable = Int. In this we are declaring the type, isn't it? Pardon me if I am wrong. – ojassethi

This is because the type will automatically recognized.
For example all Strings are declared with quotation marks

```
let myString = "Hello" // The right Value is a String, so the variable is of the type string
```

While on the other hand it could mistake a value if you are not precisely using =

```
let myDouble = 1   // myDouble is an Int! not a Double, because for the compiler 1 is an Int
let myDouble: Double = 1 // Now myDouble is a Double
let myDouble = 1.0 // Now myDouble also is a Double
```

Comment: when we use = also while declaring the type. For example- var anyVariable = Int. In this we are declaring the type, isn't it? Pardon me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ojassethi the statement 'var anyVariable = Int' will produce next compiler errors. error: expected member name or constructor call after type name
, note: add arguments after the type to construct a value of the type and finally note: use '.self' to reference the type object. 'var anyVariable1 = Int.allZeros' 
'var anyVariable2 = Int(0)' 
'var anyVariable3 = Int.self' are valid expressions